# Visa refusal. Planning to reapply

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, filipino-citizens

[image]

Hi,

I applied for a UK Visa and got refused. I am planning to reapply and make my case stronger. However, I just have a few questions and I am hoping you can help me with it.

As stated in the letter,  the reason for my refusal was because I did not provide any bank statement on my own and relay heavenly on the Sponsorship letter and Bank Statement provided by my Brother-in-law. At that time, we didn't really know that I have to prove my own my financial capacity since it was a well-funded trip. I guess my fault as I did not provide enough intent of leaving according to them even if I already gave documents supporting my claim as a student. I provided my Certificate of Enrollment, Registration Form, and Letter of Leave of Absence from the school. I already included my accommodation and round-trip ticket that were all provided by my Brother-in-law. The reason for the generosity was because, for 2 weeks,  I will be accompanying my sister for awhile since she will give birth soon. I have no immigration history or whatsoever and it will be my first out of the country travel. I only agree because my sister is my best friend and she always wanted me to be by her side once she gave birth.

They questioned me as to where I get my daily expenses if I am a student so to my reapplication, will it be safe to include my own bank statement? There are large deposits on my bank mainly because I am the sole caretaker of my sickly Father. I am just reluctant that they will see this as fund parking (I get this idea from reading other thread). Should I include my Father Medical documents to prove that he was admitted to the Hospital and that was the reason for the large deposit?  My other sister from Dubai also deposits monthly there to help us with the house expense. The deposit was done through the Western Union to Bank remittance,  should I include my sister remittance slip to explain why there is large deposit going to my bank?

Aside from that, I did not include on my first application that I am a part-time writer. This is because I get paid through remittances so this would not show on my Bank Statement.  Should I include this now and provide the remittance history or would this hurt my reapplication because I neglect to add this? I was planning to add this to my reapplication and will include my self-employment status (a certificate stating I am a freelance writer online)  provided by our local government unit. It is a notarized and dry seal of legality. I also acquired my Income Tax Return and it will show my self-employed status. Would adding all these docs help my case or I am just overthinking too much?

The letter also stated that I have no property, investment and economic circumstances that I will tie me to the Philippines so they are not satisfied that I will leave the UK after my visit. My Family do have a property, it is a land that we bought and converted into an apartment. The contract of lease was under my name stating that I am the center. However,  the land title was not transferred to us yet. We were planning to transfer this after I supposedly came back from the UK since my sister (the one who is pregnant and I will be visiting) is the owner. We were planning to let her sign the documents for the transferring. The Deed of Sale is under my name but not yet notarized. Should I include this still? If so,  would I add a cover letter explaining this? I also have a newly open Business (a motor shop accessories store) that my boyfriend and I started last September. The contract of lease is also under my name but we did not have a business permit yet since we are just testing the location of our place. Should I include this and just register it under my name? Would this help my case more?

I will also add that my sister suffers from Beta Hemolytic strep in pregnancy that makes her feel ill now. This is the primary reason why I wanted to go to the UK to at least be with her in the meantime. Should we also include this to my reapplication and provide the medical documents needed?

Please enlighten me. I appreciate your response.

Comment: I will also add that my sister suffers from Beta Hemolytic strep in Pregnancy that makes her feel ill now. This is the primary reason why I wanted to go to UK to at least be with her for the meantime. Should we also include this to my reapplication and provide the medical documents needed? Thank you.

Comment: A few points: 1) You do not usually get large amounts of money paid to you just because you are somebody's caretaker. Where are the deposits you mention coming from? Not that I want to know the answer, but the visa officials will. 2) Buying a property  is not a good indication that you will return to your country if the previous owner did not live in the country. If she managed it without living there, so could you.

Comment: Ah no, it was deposited because we have to pay the Hospital Bills. Not because I am the care taker =) That's why I asked if I should include my Father's Medical documents to prove that my father was admitted to the hospital at the time the money was deposited. The deposits are coming from remittances by my elder sister. I still have the copy of that said remittance, should I include this? As for question 2, the property is currently under my name. Along with the contract of lease that I am the landlord. Would this help my case?