# Additional documents to provide, will this help my case or not?

Tags: filipino-citizens

I've been reading a few important posts here and I just want some sort guidance, divine intervention, validation or just hey this is what we can help you with type of answer.

I know there is no universal way to know how to pass the visa application but this is my past post:

[VISA refusal, Planning to Reapply](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/105049/visa-refusal-planning-to-reapply)

It was tagged as duplicate however I have entirely different circumstances. I am planning to reapply again. (It would be my second time.)

My first application was sponsored and we provided all the necessary documents for it. I understand the reasoning behind the refusal. The second application is still sponsored.

In this second application, these will be the documents I have provided before in which I will include again: the sponsorship letter, bank statements of sponsor, accommodation, return ticket, travel insurance. My school certification and leave of absence.

Before, we thought that was enough. I am glad I have found this site though =)

Now, these are the additional documents that I will provide:

- 6 months of bank statements.
- Proof of remittance from my sponsor (bank transfer transaction, HSBC to my local bank).
- Proof of remittance from my elder sister. (She sends money monthly to help with the school expenses and for my father's medicine.) This will also be reflected in my bank statements.
- Affidavit of Profession given by the Bureau of Internal Revenue in my home country that I am a freelance writer.
- My tax forms (updated) that states that I pay my tax as a freelance writer.
- My other certification from the review school that I attend as I plan to take the board exam for my bachelor course. (Enrolment form) until Nov-May
- Medical documents of my father since I am the sole caretaker of him and schedule forms of our next check-ups.
- Letter from someone that he will be the one to look after him while I am away.
- Contract of lease under my name.

I read that writers are high-risk from IO since we can easily go underground and I was advised not to include this. Would my bank account be sufficient ties to my home country? I have activities to my account but I do not have enough savings since I am just a part-time writer and I am still a student. The contract of lease is under my name but the land title of the property is not. (This property is from my sister)

Please advise.

Would the documents I have included will help me or hurt my application further?

Thank you, 
Bella

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please read our [canonical question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e) on UK visa refusals, which contains a wealth of information. Unfortunately we are unable to predict whether or not you will actually receive the visa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must say that from the ECO's point of view your case still appears weak. The fact that your hosts in Britain are sponsoring you instead of your parents or spouse is weak point #1. In real world cases of sponsorship aside from family members mentioned above are rare. It is, therefore, a yellow flag.

Secondly, your weak point #2 is your profession. You want to be a full-time student and a part-time freelance writer at the same time, and in both cases you're stuck in the middle (for lack of adequate and clear cut proof of how you're supported as a FT student and lack of enough income as PT freelance writer to establish your solvency)

Being a part-time writer will not add strength to your case, especially since those funds are not deposited into your bank account. And the fact that your part-time earnings come from freelance writing does not prove your ties to the country. On the contrary, it gives the impression that you can continue to do so from the UK should you decide not to return to the Philippines.

Furthermore, the fact that you are the sole caretaker of your father works both ways. On one hand it may show that you intend to return to your country because you have a sick parent to take care of, but it may also mean that you might not be able to afford the trip due to medical costs associated with the caretaking of your parent. Showing docs to prove his medical needs as well as the money that your sisters deposit in your account from Britain and Dubai complicates the case prima facie and when ECO is doubtful of yoru case, his or her gut reaction is to strike it down.

Property which is not in your name but your sister's and the lease of the same that is in your name - again, this is not clear cut and a cause of confusion for the visa officer. Another yellow flag.

Including a letter from college that shows your degree exams are due soon is the only positive point that may show ties to your country. What is your official purpose of visiting Britain? Perhaps write a letter explaining your sister's situation and the help she needs during that period from a family member (you) and hope for the best.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi! Just an update. I received my visa today and the whole thread helps me a lot. Thank you everyone for the insightful advices and tips.